# HashTable is empty

Tags: python, hashtable

I am trying to implement a hash table with chaining. (m = 191) 
But when I test my code the table appears empty!

```
table = [[] for x in range(191)]

def hash_function (k):
  return k % 191

def insert (table,key):
  table[hash_function(key)].append((hash_function(key),key))

with open("test.txt", "r") as file:
   for seq in file:
      seq_int= [ord(c) for c in seq]
      int = seq_int[0] * 128 ** 3 \
          + seq_int[1] * 128 ** 2 \
          + seq_int[2] * 128 + seq_int[3]
      insert(table,int)

print table
```

I am reading the string from a text file that contains 1000 words (one per line) of length 4.

Comment: First, calling a variable `int` is a **very bad** idea, because `int()` is a built-in function. second, what's the point of inserting a tuple of key an value into the list if the key is the list index? Third, `table` is a global variable, there is no point in passing it as a parameter to the `hash_function`.

Comment: I ran your code, and `table` isn't empty.

Comment: It does not showing anything after running the insert().

Answer (score 0):

This might not be exactly what you're looking for, but you should look into using defaultdict in the future (for, e.g. cleanly building dictionaries where the value is a list that you're building and where that list should be initialized to the empty-list on the first key-access).

https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict